# How do I install a desktop environment on Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: xubuntu, kubuntu, lightdm, raspberrypi

I'm trying to configure Ubuntu 20.04 on my Raspberry Pi 4 without success.

I've tried to use XFCE installing xubuntu-desktop. Everything works without the network manager which says my wifi device isn't ready even if I am online (because I've edited the network-config file). So I cannot change network and Cockpit cannot identify it.

I've created a new SD and this time I've tried to use KDE installing kubuntu-desktop. If I choose LightDM then I can see the login screen but I've receive the error "Failed to start session". If I choose sddm I cannot reach the login screen. Moreover ssh isn't working even if the service is active.

I've followed the official tutorial, nothing more.

Comment: [This](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#1-overview) is the official tutorial and talks about installing DE.

Comment: The "optional step" to install a DE in that tutorial is new to me so thanks for pointing it out.  I wonder if this was tested... Are you using the arm64 or armhf image?  You may need to switch to whichever one you aren't using. Nearly all desktop environments these days don't need to run on anything but x86-64 instructions, which is one reason raspi devices might have issues with particular software, in addition to other hardware limitations.  See if you can dig deeper to find a root cause for the installation failures

Comment: I'm using the arm64 image. Moreover I found that if I install xfce (with xubuntu-desktop) I can access KDE from gdm so probably there is an issue with sddm and lightdm.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a partial solution in [other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209145/unable-to-boot-to-desktop-after-installing-ubuntu-19-10-1-on-raspberry-pi-4-and) request.
To make kubuntu boots correctly tou have to edit the file /boot/firmware/syscfg.txt adding this lines

```
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
disable_overscan=1
```

I don't know why I cannot see wifi networks even if I'm on line but I'll ask this in another question because is more specific.